# HTML Shows PHP file as a plain text

Tags: php, html, web, error-handling

I learn coding in my free time and I tried creating HTML website referring to PHP file. I know that similar problem was discussed here already, but I am NOT using Apache or something and I am beginner, so I did not really understand that answers - can you anyone explain more easy way?

This is my **HTML code:**

```
     <form action = "prihlaseni.php" method = "POST" >
      <input type = "text" name= "uzivatel" placeholder = "uzivatelske jmeno">
      <br>
      <input type = "password" name= "heslo" placeholder = "heslo">
      <br>
      <button type = "submit">PRIHLASIT</button>
      <br>
      </form>
```

I read that it should call the PHP file and execute code in it. Here is my **PHP file:**

```
<?php
 $uzivatel  = $_POST['uzivatel'];
 $heslo  = $_POST['heslo'];
 echo $uzivatel;
 echo $heslo;
?>
```

I thought that the website will show the text called "uzivatel" and "heslo", but it shows the code (up here) as a plain text. I am enclosing a picture of it:

[image]

Would you explain me why, someone?

Comment: You need a web server and the PHP interpreter. The browser show you what it loaded from disk, it doesn't know how to run the PHP code.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer. As I said, I am total begginer. I thought that if I put html and php file in the same folder then it works like html + css / js. It doesnt? Sorry if I sound really silly ;)

Comment: @Radek ... Check This ... : http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/0xvt-4qfc

Comment: @Radek . if You are beginner then follow this tutorial its help you to learn :: https://www.w3schools.com/php/   ....

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar Woah, it works! Thank you so much. But, please, what does "if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['uzivatel']) && !empty($_POST['heslo']) ){" mean? I dont want to copy paste thing I dont understand.. Can you explain really quick how does it solve the issue and what does it mean?
Also, thank you so much for your help. I wish you really happy life.

Comment: @Radek .. Don't  jump to the code direct first start from the basic things ..  if want to know what i actually did here before that you have to learn the basic thing from the https://www.w3schools.com/php/   ... After than you easily understand what is going here...

Comment: @Radek... `if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['uzivatel']) && !empty($_POST['heslo']) ){  //code of your echo to data  }` .. Here actually .... first one if condition i checked that submit button is acutally press or means its set or not , if its set then use `AND` & `&&` to check another 2 more fields `uzivatel` and `heslo` are not empty   `!  Means (not)` then in side that if i `echo` the your `Post` request data.

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar ok, thanks, I will go through the tutorial... ;)

Comment: @Radek .. Yupp its easy just try it your self :)

Comment: Alright, thanks. i will go see the tutorial now. Thanks a lot for all your help. I guess that teher was simply something important missing in my code...
have a nice day